# iScroll demands you define a width and height but if you have a responsive website how can you define a width?

Tags: jquery, css

My website is responsive and I'm looking to add iScroll 5 to my mobile site, the problem I'm having is that unless I define a width and height everything becomes jerky when scrolling.

for instance I have a a bunch of divs with `width:100%;` or divs that get larger with content so how can I define a height and width like so:

"iScroll needs to know the exact dimensions of both the wrapper and the scroller. They are computed at start up but if your elements change in size, we need to tell iScroll that you are messing with the DOM."

Comment: Why don't you just not use it or look for an alternative. I am sure it is not essential to use this

Comment: @Huangism Well, yea, that's an option, that's always an option but I was more curious as to how one would go about doing it. What would happen if I gave up and switched to another technology every time I got stuck on something...

Comment: Whoever made iScroll was probably not thinking of responsiveness. It seems to me that this tool is just not made for this kind of job. The only thing I can think of, is that you would have to stick with fixed width and create a few different breakpoints to change the width accordingly.

Comment: Yea, you're probably right, I'll do something else.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get your problem.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="scroller">
        <div class="content">
            <!-- Stuff -->
        <div>
    <div>
<div>
```

If you pack your content like this you just have to define width and height for "wrapper" and "scroller". Only set width for your content.

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative; /* or absolute */
}
.scroller {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
}
```

You don't need to set height.
Just refresh iScroll after resize to get new dimensions:

```
var scroller = new IScroll('#wrapper', {
    scrollX: false,
    scrollY: true,
    momentum: true,
    useTransform: true,
    useTransition: true,
    click: true
});

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        scroller.refresh();
    }, 100);
});
```